# get all graph data including nodes and relationships from neo4j using java into a hashmap

Tags: java, session, neo4j, hashmap, cypher

I am trying to get all graph data including nodes and relationships from neo4j using java into a Hashmap to be able to read all nodes and their data for further manipulation with the data. I have tried using this query but it returns an error.

```
try (Session session = driver.session()) { 
    return session.run("MATCH (m) RETURN m");
}
```

I am trying to figure out how can I get the data in the right format.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Result to List<String> ` Now i don't know how to parse Neo4j Result

Answer (score 1):

You can use below example to parse the result from neo4j query. If you get into any issue(s), pls let me know. Thanks.

```
Iterator<Node> javaNodes = execResult.columnAs("m");
for (Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable(javaNodes))
{
    //parse the node in here
}
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/cypher-java/